# Differences and uses between WSGI, CGI, FastCGI, and mod_python in regards to Python?

Tags: python, cgi, fastcgi, wsgi, mod-python

I'm just wondering what the differences and advantages are for the different CGI's out there. Which one would be best for python scripts, and how would I tell the script what to use?

Comment: Is mod_wsgi faster? My current server uses CGI, what reasons are there to switch?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219110/how-python-web-frameworks-wsgi-and-cgi-fit-together

Comment: We can't tell you if mod_wsgi will be faster in your environment.  You have to actually measure them in your environment with your constraints and your applications and your configuration.

Comment: `mod_wsgi` is Apache only. Is it still the most popular in 2012?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

A part answer to your question, including scgi.

- [What's the difference between scgi and wsgi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257481/whats-the-difference-between-scgi-and-wsgi)
- [Is there a speed difference between WSGI and FCGI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747266/is-there-a-speed-difference-between-wsgi-and-fcgi)
- [How Python web frameworks, WSGI and CGI fit together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219110/how-python-web-frameworks-wsgi-and-cgi-fit-together)

> CGI vs FCGI

Lazy and not writing it on my own. From the wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI

*Instead of creating a new process for each request, FastCGI uses persistent processes to handle such requests. Multiple processes can configured, increasing stability and scalability. Each individual FastCGI process can handle many requests over its lifetime, thereby avoiding the overhead of per-request process creation and termination*

Comment: There is a FastCGI stdio library (marcos) that let you make a single program capable of running both as CGI and as FastCGI app: http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fastcgi-prog-guide/ap_guide.htm

Comment: Question about FastCGI: How it handle simultaneous connections with one process when PHP itself is blocking language ? What if  I have something "sleep(100)" . Wont it block the process for the other users ? Thanks

Answer (score 19):

There's also a good background reader  on CGI, WSGI and other options, in the form of an official python HOWTO: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html

Comment: This is a great resource for beginners.

Comment: Looks like the url is obsolete. But this one works: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html

Answer (score 13):

In a project like [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), you can use a WSGI ([Web Server Gateway Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface)) server from the [Flup module](http://www.saddi.com/software/flup/).

A WSGI server wraps a back-end process using one or more protocols:

- [FastCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) (calling a server process)
- SCGI ([Simple Common Gateway Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Common_Gateway_Interface) - a simpler FastCGI)
- AJP ([Apache JServ Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_JServ_Protocol) - a Java FastCGI)
- [mod_python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod_python) (runs pre-loaded code per request - uses lots of RAM)
- CGI ([Common Gateway Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface), starts a process per request - slow)

In 2019, WSGI was superseded by ASGI ([Asynchronous Server Gateway Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_Server_Gateway_Interface)), used by frameworks like [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) on servers like [Uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/), which is [much faster](https://christophergs.com/python/2021/06/16/python-flask-fastapi/).

Answer (score 6):

- **FastCGI is a kind of CGI which is long-live, which will always be running.**
- **With FastCGI, it'll take less time.**
- **Because of multi-processes, FastCGI will cost more memory than CGI.**

[In Detail Diff between FastCGI vs CGI](https://aleen42.gitbooks.io/personalwiki/content/qa/cgi_difference.html)