# Python cgi or wsgi

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi, mod-wsgi, wsgi

Hi everyone i'm working on a social network project . I'm using Pythons Common Gateway Interface to write everything ,handle database , ajax . So i have a question , i heard that Web Server Gateway Interface is better than Common Gateway Interface and can handle more users and higher traffic but now i have already finished my website more than half of the project . What should i do now ? i don't have much time to going back either.Is Python Common Gateway Interface that bad for large scale project ?

Comment: Why don't you test your application and see how many concurrent users it can handle?

Comment: Possible repeat.

Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937224/differences-and-uses-between-wsgi-cgi-fastcgi-and-mod-python-in-regards-to-py .

Comment: so what should i do now  ? code everything back to WSGI ?

Comment: @user3126501: Is your webapp so low-level that this makes a huge difference?

Comment: sorry i don't understand what do you mean

Comment: Replacing CGI interface with WSGI doesn't seem like a hard thing to do. But you say large scale, and yet you're coding it in pure CGI without any framework?

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead with your work.. It will be fine if you are using Common Gateway Interface but you should have a look at network traffic.