# How to differentiate between GET and POST in plain CGI

Tags: python, cgi

I have learned a few programming languages in past such as J2EE, and I am acquainted with PHP, etc.

Most of the languages have specific methods to extract data from the POST or GET.
PHP has the `$_POST` & `$_GET` array while J2EE has `doGet()` & `doPost()` methods.

While learning Python, I found that both data in GET and POST can be extracted using `abc = cgi.FieldStorage()` and then be evaluated. Now, if I make a website using this, won't there be a security hole? Suppose a page gets data using POST, but some user goes to the page directly and feeds some GET data in the URL.

So, is there a way so that I can check whether the webpage is getting a POST or GET request without using frameworks like Django? I found out it can be done using Django or other frameworks, but I am trying to find a generic Python solution.

Comment: There is no generic solution if you are going to be using a framework to serve data - use the framework specific solution to check for GET/POST values.

Comment: I dont want to use any framework. Just the normal Python language and its CGI scripts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CGI passes metadata via [well-known environment variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface#Syntax). In this case, the "GET/POST" information is supplied via REQUEST_METHOD.

This can be accessed as so

```
import os
print os.environ['REQUEST_METHOD']
```

(There are also [SCGI / WSGI / FastCGI / etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937224/differences-and-uses-between-wsgi-cgi-fastcgi-and-mod-python-in-regards-to-py) protocols, each with their own design and rules.)